# make Jquery Slider autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-slider

I am making a `jquery` slider. code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentPosition = 0;
  var slideWidth = 560;
  var slides = $('.slide');
  var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

  // Remove scrollbar in JS
  $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

  // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
  slides
    .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
    // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
    .css({
      'float' : 'left',
      'width' : slideWidth
    });

  // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
  $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);

  // Insert controls in the DOM
  $('#slideshow')
    .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Clicking moves left</span>')
    .append('<span class="control" id="rightControl">Clicking moves right</span>');

  // Hide left arrow control on first load
  manageControls(currentPosition);

  // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
  $('.control')
    .bind('click', function(){
    // Determine new position
    currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;

    // Hide / show controls
    manageControls(currentPosition);
    // Move slideInner using margin-left
    $('#slideInner').animate({
      'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
    });
  });

  // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
  function manageControls(position){
    // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
    if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
    // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
    if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{ $('#rightControl').show() }
  } 
});
```

This is working fine and HTML code is

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="slidesContainer">
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>Web Development Tutorial</h2>
        <p><a href="#"><img src="img/img_slide_01.jpg" alt="An image that says Install X A M P P for wordpress." width="215" height="145" /></a>If you're into developing web apps, you should check out the tutorial called "<a href="#">Using XAMPP for Local WordPress Theme Development</a>" which shows you how to set up a local testing server for developing PHP/Perl based applications locally on your computer. The example also shows you how to set up WordPress locally!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>Grunge Brushes, Anyone?</h2>
        <p><a href="#"><img src="img/img_slide_02.jpg" width="215" height="145" alt="A thumbnail image that says S R grunge photoshop brushes 6 high resolution grunge brushes by six revisions." /></a>In this layout, I used <a href="#">SR Grunge</a>, which is a free set of high-resolution Photoshop brushes you can download here on Six Revisions.</p>
        <p> 
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>How About Some Awesome Grunge Textures?</h2>
        <p><a href="#"><img src="img/img_slide_03.jpg" width="215" height="145" alt="A thumbnail image that says grunge extreme 15 free high resolution grunge textures six revisions." /></a>The texture used in this web page is from the Grunge Extreme Textures freebie set by JC Parmley released here on Six Revisions.</p>
        <p>You can head over to the <a href="#">Grunge Extreme</a> page to download the texture set or check out Six Revisions' <a href="#">freebie section</a> for even more goodies!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>'Tis the End, My Friend.</h2>
        <p><a href="#"><img src="img/img_slide_04.jpg" width="215" height="145" alt="Thumbnail image that says sleek button using photoshop that links to a Photoshop tutoril." /></a>This is the last slide. Hit the left arrow control to go back to the other slides.</p>
        <p>Alternatively, you may want to check out the tutorial on how to create a simple and cool button in Photoshop called &quot;<a href="#">How to Create a Slick and Clean Button in Photoshop</a>&quot; which was inspired by the <a href=#">Campaign Monitor</a> web interface.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Slideshow HTML -->

</div>
```

This working fine with the left and right arrow. Now I want to make it autoplay. So please tell me how can I make it autoplay slider.

Comment: Just trigger click on #rightControl after certain intervals, that will be autoplay for you. http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/215/

Comment: Is this what u want ?http://jsfiddle.net/n8B2k/

Comment: yes but i want it in the cycle. If last is gone then it stop i want that if last slide come the it restart from slide first.

Comment: Pratik yes but it is not in loop. After last slide it start from the first slide

Comment: Is this what u want ?http://jsfiddle.net/n8B2k/

Comment: No Pratik.. It is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8B2k/1/)

Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var currentPosition = 0;
      var slideWidth = 560;
      var slides = $('.slide');
      var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

      // Remove scrollbar in JS
      $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

      // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
      slides
        .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
        // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
        .css({
          'float' : 'left',
          'width' : slideWidth
        });

      // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
      $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);

      // Insert controls in the DOM
      $('#slideshow')
        .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Clicking moves left</span>')
        .append('<span class="control" id="rightControl">Clicking moves right</span>');

      // Hide left arrow control on first load
      manageControls(currentPosition);

      // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
      $('.control')
        .bind('click', function(){
        // Determine new position
        currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;

        // Hide / show controls
        manageControls(currentPosition);
        // Move slideInner using margin-left
        $('#slideInner').animate({
          'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
        });
      });

      // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
      function manageControls(position){
                if(position >= 3)
                {
                    position=0;
                    currentPosition=0;
                }
        // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
        if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
        // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
        if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{ $('#rightControl').show() }
      } 

      function Aplay(){
        // Determine new position
        currentPosition =  currentPosition+1 ;

        // Hide / show controls
        manageControls(currentPosition);
        // Move slideInner using margin-left
        $('#slideInner').animate({
          'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
        });
          setTimeout(function(){Aplay();},2000);
      }
      setTimeout(Aplay(),20000);

});
```

Comment: @Ankur ,Hi wats the problem?

Comment: how to make it stop on mouseover. Slides not stopping on mouseover. Can you guide me?

Comment: @Ankur , Sure .Please post it as a new Question you u will also Get +1 ,and i will get +1 too ,as i will solve ur problem.good for both,please

Comment: Ok i will post the new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503402/make-jquery-slider-stop-on-mouse-hover here the new question

Comment: Rookie mistake .. jocking.. please don't use the brackets in Aplay() because it will execute the function before starting the settimeout function. you just need Aplay

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use animate complete function.

when animate is complete start another animate or move back.

```
 $('#slideInner').animate({
  'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
}, function() { Your Code Here });
```

see [Jquery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)