# Cancel Jquery Slider event on mousehover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I wrote the following code to attempt to cancel an event on mousehover. the goal is to keep the slide event from happening if a slide is currently being hovered. Is it possible to cancel the slide event if the current slide is being hovered? Here is my code:

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentPosition = 0;
  var slideWidth = 560;
  var slides = $('.slide');
  var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

  // Remove scrollbar in JS
  $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

  // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
  slides
    .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
    // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
    .css({
      'float' : 'left',
      'width' : slideWidth
    });

  // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
  $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);

  // Insert controls in the DOM
  $('#slideshow')
    .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Clicking moves left</span>')
    .append('<span class="control" id="rightControl">Clicking moves right</span>');

  // Hide left arrow control on first load
  manageControls(currentPosition);

  // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
  $('.control')
    .bind('click', function(){
    // Determine new position
    currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;

    // Hide / show controls
    manageControls(currentPosition);
    // Move slideInner using margin-left
    $('#slideInner').animate({
      'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
    });
  });


     // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
      function manageControls(position){
                if(position >= 4)
                {
                    position=0;
                    currentPosition=0;
                }

      } 

      function Aplay(){
        // Determine new position
        currentPosition =  currentPosition+1 ;

        // Hide / show controls
        manageControls(currentPosition);
        // Move slideInner using margin-left
        $('#slideInner').animate({
          'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
        });
          setTimeout(function(){Aplay();},5000);
      }
      setTimeout(Aplay(),50000);
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="slidesContainer">
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>Web Development Tutorial</h2>
        <p><a href="#"><img src="img/img_slide_01.jpg" alt="An image that says Install X A M P P for wordpress." width="215" height="145" /></a>If you're into developing web apps, you should check out the tutorial called "<a href="#">Using XAMPP for Local WordPress Theme Development</a>"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>Grunge Brushes, Anyone?</h2>
        <p><a href="#"><img src="img/img_slide_02.jpg" width="215" height="145" alt="A thumbnail image that says S R grunge photoshop brushes 6 high resolution grunge brushes by six revisions." /></a>In this layout, I used <a href="#">SR Grunge</a>,</p>
        <p> 
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>How About Some Awesome Grunge Textures?</h2>
        <p><a href="#"><img src="img/img_slide_03.jpg" width="215" height="145" alt="A thumbnail image that says grunge extreme 15 free high resolution grunge textures six revisions." /></a>The texture used in this web page is from the Grunge Extreme Textures freebie set by JC Parmley released here on Six Revisions.</p>
        <p>You can head over to the <a href="#">Grunge Extreme</a> page to download the texture set or check out Six Revisions' <a href="#">freebie section</a> for even more goodies!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <h2>'Tis the End, My Friend.</h2>
        <p><a href="#"><img src="img/img_slide_04.jpg" width="215" height="145" alt="Thumbnail image that says sleek button using photoshop that links to a Photoshop tutorial." /></a></p>
        <p> web interface.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Slideshow HTML -->

</div>
```

Comment: Hello,OP has his slider running like this http://jsfiddle.net/n8B2k/1/  .He wants to stop slider on hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b72RU/)

Replace the Javascript bottom part with this code:

```
 var timeout = null;
      function Aplay(){
        // Determine new position
        currentPosition =  currentPosition+1 ;

        // Hide / show controls
        manageControls(currentPosition);
        // Move slideInner using margin-left
        $('#slideInner').animate({
          'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
        });
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){Aplay();},5000);
      }
      timeout = setTimeout(function(){Aplay();},5000);

    $('#slideshow').hover(function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    },function(){
       timeout = setTimeout(function(){Aplay();},5000);
    });
```

Exaplanation:

create a variable called `timeout` that will contain the `setTimeout` event
 The `$('slideshow').hover(...)` will stop the event when the mouse is over it, then will re assign it to `timeout` when mouse exit the slideshow

**Edit**

Solution for the question by OP on the comments below:

Add this in the html:

```
<span id="numbering">1</span>
```

Add this functions in JS:

```
function updateNumber(){
     $('#numbering').text((+$('#numbering').text())%4 + 1);
}
```

Then call it in the functions that are involved with the sliding of the images, so when text clicked and when automatically sliding.

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b72RU/2/)

Comment: maybe `var timeout = null;` would be better, although i really don't know if declaring a variable in javascript will default it to null or undefined.

Comment: @r3wt yup actually :)

Comment: U gave Correct solution . +1 for u ! :)

Comment: @Amir ,did u complete jQuery/JSCript private coaching classes?

Comment: Thanks @Amir I got the solutions. Can i add numbers of slides and current slide number in the bottom.

Comment: @PratikJoshi nop, what're those

Comment: @Amir Can you give me Jquery/Jscript private coaching or some tutorials that i can learn.

Comment: @Amir i write this line to put numbers  $('#slideshow').append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav"></a><a class="nivo-nextNav"></a></div>'); now how can i show number of slide there and make it navigation

Comment: @Ankur there's plenty of tuts online, the most important thing is practicing a lot! Concerning you question about numbering the slideshows, feel free to post another question on SO because it's hard to but solutions here

Comment: @Amir please provide the solutions on the same questions

Comment: @Ankur , I just Saw this cource ,and its amazing ,by IBM developer. http://courses.tutsplus.com/courses/30-days-to-learn-jquery   .I Downloaded it from Torrent , U may buy it :)

Comment: @PratikJoshi i found it on torrent. Thanks but please tell me how to show slides numbers in there.

Comment: @Ankur , means ? i didnt get u

Comment: @PratikJoshi i want number of slides and current slide running number on the sildeinner div

Comment: U mean total slides 4 should be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

.stop() will stop all animations so try adding a mouseover to your slider elements

```
<div id="slide1" class="slide" onmouseover='$("#" + this.id).stop();'></div>
```

Or you could bind the listeners

```
$('.slide').mouseover(function(){ $("#" + this.id).stop(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

[jQuery .hover() API](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) will help you achieve what you want.